# Problem Downloading File using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation

I am trying to download a PDF file using Selenium Python and though the code runs, it does not download the file. What could be the problem?

This is the code I run:

```
url = 'http://demo.automationtesting.in/FileDownload.html'
#Load the dataset
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
def enable_download_headless(browser,download_dir):
    browser.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
    params = {'cmd':'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_dir}}
    browser.execute("send_command", params)
    
options.add_experimental_option('prefs',{
                                                        'download.default_directory' : 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Stats',
                                                        'download.prompt_for_download': False,
                                                        'safebrowsing_for_trusted_sources_enabled': False,
                                                        'download.directory_upgrade':True,
                                                        'safebrowsing.enabled':False
                                                       })
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
download_dir = 'C:/Users/USER/Desktop/Stats'
#Enable setting up headless download
enable_download_headless(browser,download_dir)
time.sleep(5)

browser.get(url)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
#Insert Text
textbox_xpath = '//*[@id="textbox"]'
textbox = browser.find_element(By.XPATH,textbox_xpath).send_keys('Hello World')
#Create Text
create_xpath= '//*[@id="createTxt"]'
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,create_xpath).click()
time.sleep(5)
#Download
download_xpath= '//*[@id="link-to-download"]'
browser.find_element(By.XPATH,download_xpath).click()
time.sleep(5)
```

I was expecting to download the file but it does not download. I can't trace the problem not even in the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

In your code the `create_xpath` and `download_xpath` both are having the same `xpath`. To download the file you have to do like below.

**Replace** this *line*

```
download_xpath= '//*[@id="createTxt"]'
```

**With** this *line*

```
download_xpath= '//*[@id="link-to-download"]'
```

Comment: Oh yes! I see that I used the same path. Thanks for that! I amended it as per your advice. However, the code runs but no file downloaded yet. It however does not display any errors. What could still be the issue? Any idea why?